# How to add minimize all windows plasmoid to quicklaunch widget in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, widgets

The screen shot below shows that the **minimize all windows** plasmoid next to the **quicklaunch** on the panel. I could not able to move it to the quicklaunch. I also tried to find any command or script that minimize all windows in the KDE in order to make a shortcut for it and then drag it into the quicklaunch but I could not find any thing.

Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Comment: My guess is that quicklaunch only accepts applications and not plasmoids? I tried adding various widgets to quicklaunch without any luck. I don't use the "Minimize all Windows", because there's a convenient "Show Desktop" keyboard shortcut that does the same thing without taking up space on the panel. I think the default shortcut is `Meta+D`. `grep "Show Desktop" ~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc` may list the shortcut.

Comment: By the way, I don't use the quicklaunch widget. I have keyboard shortcuts for my most commonly uses: `Meta+F` for Firefox, `Meta +K` for Kate, `Meta+Ctrl+D` bound to `spectacle -b -u -d 10000 -o $HOME/Pictures/"$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)".png` to take a delayed screenshot (without going through Spectacle's GUI), etc.

Comment: @DKBose Please checkout the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution.

1. Install `xdotool` `sudo apt install xdotool` to simulate keyboard strokes from the terminal. [Reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267704/command-to-simulate-keyboard-input)
2. Create the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
xdotool key super+d
```

3. Save it as anything, `minimize.sh` at your home directory.
4. At your home terminal write `chmod +x minimize.sh` to make it executable.
5. Create a desktop link to that script **OR** drag and drop the script file into the quicklaunch widget.

Now the Minimize all windows functionality is available.
[image]

This Minimize All.desktop entry to make it as launcher file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
Exec=/home/saidbakr/minimize.sh
GenericName[en_US]=
GenericName=
Icon=
MimeType=
Name[en_US]=Minimize All
Name=MinimizeAll
Path=/home/saidbakr
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```

#### Notice:

The shortcut key, *in this case*, `super+d` should be active by any mean. One of those way, is to add minimize all widget to your desktop and assigning a keyboard shortcut key to it equals to the combination declared in the bash script file. i.e *in this case* `super+d`